# Jquery/Javascript - Can't increment number (tweet-id)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, integer, increment

I don't get it.
I can't increment the Tweet-ID ...

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/idupoq/1/edit

```
glb = {};
glb.lastTweetId = 0;

getTweets();

function getTweets()
{
    console.info('# LAST ID');
    console.log(glb.lastTweetId);

    console.info('# TEST 1');
    glb.lastTweetId++;
    console.log(glb.lastTweetId);  

    console.info('# TEST 2');
    glb.lastTweetId = glb.lastTweetId+1;
    console.log(glb.lastTweetId);  

    console.info('# TEST 3, OK IS INT BUT PARSE AGAIN ');
    glb.lastTweetId = parseInt(glb.lastTweetId);
    glb.lastTweetId++;
    console.log(glb.lastTweetId);  

    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23wwm&since_id='+glb.lastTweetId+'&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&lang=de&callback=?', function(data, textStatus)
    {
        if(data.results.length > 0)
        {
            glb.lastTweetId = data.results[0]['id'];
        }
        glb.tm= setTimeout('getTweets();',5000);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The jsbin works if you delete the `console.info` lines, use `console.log` instead

Comment: sure? http://jsbin.com/idupoq/4/edit ... you must wait 5 seconds ;)

Comment: `271567725082578940` exceeds the range of integer

[See this](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/HqpVc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said already, it is because of Number cannot express `271567725082578941`. If all you ever want to do to this number is to increase it by one, then the following function should be all you need:

```
function stringInc(v){
    var digits = v.toString().split('');
    var i = digits.length-1;
    while (digits[i]==9 && i>0){      
      digits[i] = 0;
      i--;
    }
    digits[i] = 1+parseInt(digits[i]);
    return digits.join('');
}
```

If you expect to want to do something more with the number, then you might be better off using a BigNumber library as suggested by VisioN.

Either way, you should note that you cannot read the tweet id from `data.results[0]['id']`, because that is interpreted as a Number and rounded to `271567725082578940`. You need to use `data.results[0]['id_str']`.

See updated jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/idupoq/19/. Notice the console is logging the result from the server:

```
...

"geo":null,
"id":     271580395022217200,
"id_str":"271580395022217216",
"iso_language_code":"de"

...
```

So the value `271567725082578940` that you have been observing is incorrect as well.

Answer (score 7):

This happens because the received ID is out of range of [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) format, e.g.

```
271567725082578940 + 1 = 271567725082578940
```

You should use special libraries to work with large numbers. Some examples:

- https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum
- http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber

Answer (score 1):

Dirty but short
http://jsbin.com/idupoq/18/edit

```
    glb.lastTweetId = ''+data.results[0]['id']+'';
    var lastTwoDig = parseInt(glb.lastTweetId.substr(glb.lastTweetId.length-2));
    var startDigit = glb.lastTweetId.substring(0, glb.lastTweetId.length-2);
    lastTwoDig++;
    if(lastTwoDig==01){ lastTwoDig = '01'; }
    console.log(glb.lastTweetId);
    console.log(' '+startDigit+''+lastTwoDig+' ');
```

Comment: What if the last digits are `...99`? I think e.g. `123499` will become `1234100` then.